# Display Fields of Relationship Query in Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relationship, laravel-blade

After binding tables in a model and writing a query, fetched data in a Blade shows error.

> Trying to get property of non-object

**Model**

```
<?php

public function unit()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('TEST\Units');
}
```

**Query**

```
$inst = Instructions::with('unit')
     ->where('id',$inst_id)
     ->first()
     ->get();
```

**Model**

```
@foreach ($inst as $item)
    <pre>{{$item->units->name}}</pre>
@endforeach
```

However, when using this code and I delete a name or other field, no error displays...

```
@foreach ($inst as $item)
    <pre>{{$item->units}}</pre>
@endforeach
```

output:

```
{"id":1,"name":"UNIT 101","description":null,"created_at":"2017-03-06 13:30:18","updated_at":"2017-03-06 13:30:18"}
```

Comment: You don't have to call `get` after `first`. `first` internally calls `get` method.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want to achieve, but you get 1 result (using `first()`) and then iterate through it?

Comment: i want show fetched data in my view. when use this syntax,no error         
                <pre>{{$item->units}}</pre>
   But add field to $item->units->MYFIELD error occared.i cant use field name MYFIELD

Comment: You have to rename your method to `units` instead of `unit`

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
            @foreach ($inst as $item)
                @if (!empty($item->unit->id))
                <pre>{{$item->unit->name}}</pre>
            @endif
        @endforeach
```